# How to get SecurityContext for not current user?

Tags: java, spring-security, security-context

I couldn't find an answer for that. 
I'm aware that I can get SecurityContext for currently logged user with

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
```

but I would like to get that context for not curretnly logged one. Not sure what more information I can provide to this question: I have access to his Authentication and principals that I have setted before. I probably can get more information that I would need for that.

Comment: What do you mean by `not curretnly logged one`?

Comment: you mean other users aside from the logged in user?

Comment: @jmcg yes, I meant that.

Comment: What do you need to do with the SecurityContext?